# jQuery autocomplete strange padding

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, height, padding

I have a strange probleme with jQuery Autocomplete.
I've tried to find my issue I don't.

You can see my problem with this picture:

[image]

I have a strange height between my input and my first result.

The CSS code I put is :

```
.ui-autocomplete {
z-index: 1000;
}

.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
display: none;
}

.ui-autocomplete {
width: 50px;
list-style: none;
background: #454545;
}

.ui-autocomplete:hover {
width: 100%;
background: #4a4a4a;
}

.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a { 
color: #00aacd;
border: 1px solid #454545;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<div class="inputdiv">
  <label class="label" for="one_input">
    Input 1 <sup><span class="star">*</span></sup>
  </label>
  <input id="one_input" type="text" name="inputone" class="input_ajout" value="">
</div>
```

[ ... ]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "test","retret","erzaerz","4sqd54cd54","sfdqdfsq","rezareza","akjjfqhjkdfsq",
    ];
    $( "#one_input" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: could you please share your HTML code?

Comment: Your code is working fine http://jsbin.com/qaqoz/1/edit , it's because of something else

Comment: Thank you mohamedrias. It don't work properly on my computer. Maybe it is the OS? CentOS v6

Comment: No. Someother code is adding padding. Could you paste the site link here/

Comment: I can't. I work in localhost within an enterprise. Ok I know now that my code is well. Thank you for putting me on the track!

Comment: Then more code is required, can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Indeed, there is a padding probleme but I don't find it. Thank you